# assetic use_controller -> true very slow : Symfony 2

Tags: php, performance, symfony, assetic

I use assetic to manage js files in my project. Every thing is ok in prod environnement but it's very slow in dev.

In prod environnement, i have no problem with that as i dump all assets with "php app/console assetic:dump" command

In dev environnement, i dont want to assetic dump each time i modify my js files so i have this conf in my config_dev.yml file :

```
assetic:
  use_controller: true
```

Take a look at network in my web browser : 
[image]

Thx for help

Comment: What help do you want? This is precisely why the controller is disabled by default in production.

Comment: Is there a way  to speed up this because i don't want assetic dump to execute assetic:dump (far toot long) each time i want to test my js

Answer (score 0):

Assetic is very powerful and practice. Moreover it allow you to work correctly in particular mean that separate the /web directory and your bundle directory for delivery assets and not just put into the /web directory basically with copy/paste.

But it's very important to say that assetic bundle is not delivery with standard edition of symfony...

If you don't want with Assetic you can :

- just copy/paste your JS, CSS files into /web directory (ordering by
  another directory of your choice into /web) and edit those directly
  in this path.
- You can use Assetic but with --watch option. With this option you never dump manually your assets : `php bin/console assetic:watch`
- You can use Grunt or another tool for design process that running automatically your delivery or treatment files.
- You can also disable assetic just for 1 file during your development
- You can reduce your number of files JS, CSS for process of dump assetic (I don't know if you win lot of time...)
- You can work directly into the /web directory during all your develoment time before your application run first time in production
  and after use assetic for delivery in production in first time.
- switch between compressor minification and nothing for your assets for understanding if this task assetic is very long.

You can mix all of this idea for find your favorite workflow process for developing your assets.

**Last idea (best for me)** : Learn to develop your code with many new line before dump and view the result. Less dump assets and more coding with debugging message for understanding immediatly errors.